# How to integrate Facebook Sharing to PC software?

Tags: windows, facebook, unity-game-engine, sdk

I'm trying to enable image sharing to Facebook in my PC standalone software built with Unity 3D without relying on an external web browser.

After some research, it seems that Facebook does have a windows SDK. However it's specifically for UWP apps: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/windows-sdk/

In the meantime, Facebook is pushing out Games SDK for PC, which seems to include social sharing API as well, but it's still in beta: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/pc-games

Worst comes to worst, I can just use their Graph API, but it looks like the access token has to be retrieved through an embedded webpage, which I'm avoiding.

Comment: (Regarding that last part: You can not post to user profiles using the API any more, the permissions necessary for that have been removed a while ago.)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Looks like Facebook sharing is simply impossible without using their SDK at this point?